# Which single board computer should I chose?

Tags: ros, opencv, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ros community

I' m working with ros to make a robot which can go itself with image proccessing. I am using lots of hardware in this project and I used pcduino V3 until this time. But I want to change pcduino because I' m having some trouble with it.

I looked lots of single board compuers on the internet and finally find 4 boards to chosing. But I cannot decide which board I should choice for best performance. Can anyone help me for it?

I can give 100$ at most, so I find:

- Banana Pi M3          ==>  1.8Ghz * 8 Cores / PowerVR SGX544MP1 / wireless / 8 Gb Emmc Flash /2 usb ports
- Orange Pi Plus 2      ==> 1.6Ghz * 4 Cores / Mali 400 Mp2            / wirekes / 16 Gb Emmc Flash / 4 usb ports
- Odroid XU4             ==> 2.0Ghz * 4 Cores + 1.4 Ghz * 4 Cores / Mali T 628 MP6 / no wireless / no flash / 3 usb ports
- Odroid C2               ==>  2.0Ghz * 4 Cores / Mali 450                   / no wireless / no flash           / 4 usb ports

Which board is the powerfull board from other boards or are there more powerpull board from these?(less $100)

Thanks a lot..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230198/which-single-board-computer-should-i-chose?/) by [baseroguzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26400/baseroguzhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-03-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-03-27**:
Take a look at the BeagleBone Black too. It costs $55 and you can install Ubuntu 14.04.x for ARMhf and ROS Indigo for ARMhf on it. It also has a ton of I/O pins.

**Comment by [baseroguzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26400/baseroguzhan/) on 2016-03-27**:
Thanks for your advice but beagle bone black' s performance is less than all off the boards in the list. So I shouldn' t prefer it.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-03-29**:
Do you run from a battery? If so you might want to ditch the Cortex A7 ones.

**Comment by [baseroguzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26400/baseroguzhan/) on 2016-03-29**:
I have to use battery because I am working with a mobile robot. But it causes power consumption problem if I choice like odroid xu4.

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-03-29**:
@Humpelstilzchen I'm curious, why is that? Does the Cortex A7 consume a lot of power? Is that also true of the A8? Thanks!

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-03-29**:
Its not that the A7 in particular consumes a lot of power, its actually pretty good. It is just that various benchmarks (including my own) seem to indicate a better performance/watt ratio for the A53 then the older A7/A8/A9.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you like to have an easy ros usage you should use a board with Ubuntu 14.04 support. With your spec I think the odroid xu4 is the best. But clock speed is not the only think. The Ram size is important to.

The other thinks are Linux drivers for open cl and open gl es, if you need some kind of visualization of ros.

The PI 3 should be nice to but there is no Ubuntu 14.04 support. You can use debian Jessie, but the environment setup is non that easy but possible.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2016-03-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baseroguzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26400/baseroguzhan/) on 2016-03-26**:
Thanks for your answer.

The ram size in these boards are same and 2 GB so I don' t need to write it. I want to chioce odroid xu4 but it has a very big power problem. How can I give it 4A without adapter?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want more powerful performance, you will usually need to provide more power, this is one of the trade-offs you need to consider.

we used x-u4 with turtlebots and were very pleased with their performance. We used http://www.amazon.co.uk/Step-Down-Step-down-Power-Module/dp/B00ENE55SQ to step down the power from the kobuki base.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baseroguzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26400/baseroguzhan/) on 2016-03-27**:
Thanks for your advice. I have one more question.

I want to use 7 A/h Li-ion battery in my project. Is it enough for this board?

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-03-27**:
Depends how long you hope it will run (and what voltage the battery is). The x-u4 only peak very briefly at more than 3A as they start up, most of the time they are in the 1-2A range, but that will also depend on what you are getting them to calculate. We used the eMMC memory option with them.

**Comment by [baseroguzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26400/baseroguzhan/) on 2016-03-27**:
Thanks again.

If I can work more than 30 minutes without charging is enough for me. Some other additional hardware (like wireless) will work with it. And 7 A/h battery will feed only them. If not enough can you advice a battery?